# Kubernetes cluster is broken: FailedSync and SandboxChanged

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes 1.7.5 cluster which has somehow gotten into a semi-broken state. Scheduling a new deployment on this cluster partially fails: 1/2 pods starts normally, but the second pod does not start. The events are:

```
default   2017-09-28 03:57:02 -0400 EDT   2017-09-28 03:57:02 -0400 EDT   1         hello-4059723819-8s35v   Pod       spec.containers{hello}   Normal    Pulled    kubelet, k8s-agentpool1-18117938-2   Successfully pulled image "myregistry.azurecr.io/mybiz/hello"
default   2017-09-28 03:57:02 -0400 EDT   2017-09-28 03:57:02 -0400 EDT   1         hello-4059723819-8s35v   Pod       spec.containers{hello}   Normal    Created   kubelet, k8s-agentpool1-18117938-2   Created container
default   2017-09-28 03:57:03 -0400 EDT   2017-09-28 03:57:03 -0400 EDT   1         hello-4059723819-8s35v   Pod       spec.containers{hello}   Normal    Started   kubelet, k8s-agentpool1-18117938-2   Started container
default   2017-09-28 03:57:13 -0400 EDT   2017-09-28 03:57:01 -0400 EDT   2         hello-4059723819-tj043   Pod                 Warning   FailedSync   kubelet, k8s-agentpool1-18117938-3   Error syncing pod
default   2017-09-28 03:57:13 -0400 EDT   2017-09-28 03:57:02 -0400 EDT   2         hello-4059723819-tj043   Pod                 Normal    SandboxChanged   kubelet, k8s-agentpool1-18117938-3   Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
default   2017-09-28 03:57:24 -0400 EDT   2017-09-28 03:57:01 -0400 EDT   3         hello-4059723819-tj043   Pod                 Warning   FailedSync   kubelet, k8s-agentpool1-18117938-3   Error syncing pod
default   2017-09-28 03:57:25 -0400 EDT   2017-09-28 03:57:02 -0400 EDT   3         hello-4059723819-tj043   Pod                 Normal    SandboxChanged   kubelet, k8s-agentpool1-18117938-3   Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
[...]
```

The last two log messages just keep repeating themselves.

The dashboard of the failed pod shows:

[image: Dashboard of failed pod]

Eventually the dashboard shows the error:

```
Error: failed to start container "hello": Error response from daemon: {"message":"cannot join network of a non running container: 7e95918c6b546714ae20f12349efcc6b4b5b9c1e84b5505cf907807efd57525c"}
```

This cluster is running on Azure using the CNI Azure networking plugin. Everything was working fine up until some time after I enabled the `--runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true` in order to use the `CronJob` functionality. Now, even after removing that API level, and rebooting the master, the problem still occurs.

The kubelet log on the node shows that an IP address cannot be allocated:

```
E0928 20:54:01.733682    1750 pod_workers.go:182] Error syncing pod 65127a94-a425-11e7-8d64-000d3af4357e ("hello-4059723819-xx16n_default(65127a94-a425-11e7-8d64-000d3af4357e)"), skipping: failed to "CreatePodSandbox" for "hello-4059723819-xx16n_default(65127a94-a425-11e7-8d64-000d3af4357e)" with CreatePodSandboxError: "CreatePodSandbox for pod \"hello-4059723819-xx16n_default(65127a94-a425-11e7-8d64-000d3af4357e)\" failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod \"hello-4059723819-xx16n_default\" network: Failed to allocate address: Failed to delegate: Failed to allocate address: No available addresses"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug with Azure CNI not always correctly recycling IP addresses from terminated pods. See this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-container-networking/issues/76.

The reason this occurred after enabling `CronJob` functionality is that cronjob containers are (usually) short-lived, and are allocated an IP every time they run. If those IPs are not recycled and re-usable by the underlying networking system -- in this case CNI -- they quickly run out.